# Is there dye that attaches only to human DNA?

Tags: dye

I am looking for simple way to tell if blood stain is from human blood or some other animals. I know there are fluorescent DNA dyes, but is there dye that only attaches to human DNA?

Comment: I highly doubt it: human DNA and DNA from other species are very similar in structure, and in some cases (eg: primates) are very similar as sequences as well.
I think that "complex" analytical techniques are necessary in order to tell human DNA from animal DNA.

Comment: It would have to be a superintelligent dye.